# Oauth client with a Doorkeeper provider behind basic authentication

Tags: ruby, heroku, omniauth, basic-authentication

We are setting up a Doorkeeper provider on our main app to enable Oauth2 authentication on some side applications. Everything's working fine on our production environement.

On the staging environment that's another story, because our staging applications are behind basic authentication :

```
config.middleware.insert_after(::Rack::Runtime,
                               'Rack::Auth::Basic',
                               "Staging") do |user, password|
                                 [user, password] == [ENV['STAGING_USERNAME'], ENV['STAGING_PASSWORD']]
                              end
end
```

Which means the Oauth endpoint must pass thru this Basic authentication. Here is the Oauth client configuration :

```
require 'omniauth-oauth2'

module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    class MyAuth < OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2
      option :name, "MyAuth"

      # Added Basic auth credentials for staging environment
      option :client_options, {:site => "https://youshall:notpass@my-staging-server.info"}

      uid{ raw_info['id'] }

      info do
        {
          remote_id: raw_info['remote_id'],
          name: raw_info['name'],
          email: raw_info['email']
        }
      end

      extra do
        {
          'raw_info' => raw_info
        }
      end

      def raw_info
        @raw_info ||= access_token.get('/api/me').parsed
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But Oauth seems not to be able to parse the URI including, as I get the following error when trying to get credentials :

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
- 51 non-project frames
1
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/oauth2-1.2.0/lib/oauth2/error.rb" line 30 in encode
2
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/oauth2-1.2.0/lib/oauth2/error.rb" line 30 in error_message
3
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/oauth2-1.2.0/lib/oauth2/error.rb" line 17 in initialize
4
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/oauth2-1.2.0/lib/oauth2/client.rb" line 112 in new
5
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/oauth2-1.2.0/lib/oauth2/client.rb" line 112 in request
6
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/oauth2-1.2.0/lib/oauth2/client.rb" line 138 in get_token
7
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/oauth2-1.2.0/lib/oauth2/strategy/auth_code.rb" line 29 in get_token
8
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/omniauth-oauth2-1.4.0/lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb" line 89 in build_access_token
9
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/omniauth-oauth2-1.4.0/lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb" line 73 in callback_phase
10
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/omniauth-1.3.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb" line 227 in callback_call
11
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/omniauth-1.3.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb" line 184 in call!
12
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/omniauth-1.3.1/lib/omniauth/strategy.rb" line 164 in call
13
File "/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/omniauth-1.3.1/lib/omniauth/builder.rb" line 63 in call
```

I couldn't find anyway to provide Basic auth credentials for Omniauth or Omniauth::Oauth2 if Oauth server is behind such authentication.

Another way could be to whitelist IP address of staging clients on the staging Oauth server. As we are using Heroku, apps run on highly dynamic IP addresses. Some heroku addons allow to route outbound trafic through statig IPs BUT I need to programmatically setup a proxy. And I could not find the way to configure this proxy for Oauth requests.

Anybody ran into such issue and found a workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

Aaaah finally it did not take me too much time to find the solution (actually writing that question was part of it :))

So omniauth-oauth2 strategy uses the [Oauth gem](https://github.com/oauth-xx/oauth2) which in turn uses the awesome [Faraday HTTP library](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday). It was not so hard to find a way to [setup a proxy in Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/issues/221).

My Omniauth stragegy now looks like this :

```
require 'omniauth-oauth2'

module OmniAuth
  module Strategies
    class MyAuth < OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2
      option :name, "MyAuth"

      # Added Basic auth credentials for staging environment
      option :client_options, {:site => "https://youshall:notpass@my-staging-server.info"}

      uid{ raw_info['id'] }

      info do
        {
          remote_id: raw_info['remote_id'],
          name: raw_info['name'],
          email: raw_info['email']
        }
      end

      extra do
        {
          'raw_info' => raw_info
        }
      end

      # Adding the proxy here
      def client
        super.tap do |c|
          c.connection.proxy(ENV["OAUTH_PROXY_URL"]) if ENV["OAUTH_PROXY_URL"]
        end
      end
      def raw_info
        @raw_info ||= access_token.get('/api/me').parsed
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And now I just need to whitelist my proxy IP to bypass the Basic authentication on the Oauth server. Voilà !